# MLT のインストール方法が分からない

Tags: windows, powershell

MLTというフレームワークが必要になりまして、サイトからダウンロードしました。
ですが、インストール方法が分からず、手間取っております。

前回、一度ダウンロードはできたのですが、手順が紛失してしまい分からなくなってしまいました。

下記がURLです。
https://www.mltframework.org/

上記URLからダウンロードを押すと、下記サイトへ。
https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/releases

参考URL
https://www.mltframework.org/docs/buildscripts/#preparation-1
https://www.mltframework.org/docs/install/
https://www.mltframework.org/docs/windowsbuild/

参考URLを見てもいまいちわかりません。
前回は、PowerSell使った覚えがあります。
インストールに成功すると、PowerSellに『melt』とコマンドすると下記のように表示されます。

```
PS C:\Users\ユーザー名> melt
Usage: melt.exe [options] [producer [name=value]* ]+
Options:
  -attach filter[:arg] [name=value]*       Attach a filter to the output
  -attach-cut filter[:arg] [name=value]*   Attach a filter to a cut
  -attach-track filter[:arg] [name=value]* Attach a filter to a track
  -attach-clip filter[:arg] [name=value]*  Attach a filter to a producer
  -audio-track | -hide-video               Add an audio-only track
  -blank frames                            Add blank silence to a track
  -chain id[:arg] [name=value]*            Add a producer as a chain
  -consumer id[:arg] [name=value]*         Set the consumer (sink)
  -debug                                   Set the logging level to debug
  -filter filter[:arg] [name=value]*       Add a filter to the current track
  -getc                                    Get keyboard input using getc
  -group [name=value]*                     Apply properties repeatedly
  -help                                    Show this message
  -jack                                    Enable JACK transport synchronization
  -join clips                              Join multiple clips into one cut
  -link id[:arg] [name=value]*             Add a link to a chain
  -mix length                              Add a mix between the last two cuts
  -mixer transition                        Add a transition to the mix
  -null-track | -hide-track                Add a hidden track
  -profile name                            Set the processing settings
  -progress                                Display progress along with position
  -query                                   List all of the registered services
  -query "consumers" | "consumer"=id       List consumers or show info about one
  -query "filters" | "filter"=id           List filters or show info about one
  -query "producers" | "producer"=id       List producers or show info about one
  -query "transitions" | "transition"=id   List transitions, show info about one
  -query "profiles" | "profile"=id         List profiles, show info about one
  -query "presets" | "preset"=id           List presets, show info about one
  -query "formats"                         List audio/video formats
  -query "audio_codecs"                    List audio codecs
  -query "video_codecs"                    List video codecs
  -quiet                                   Set the logging level to quiet
  -remove                                  Remove the most recent cut
  -repeat times                            Repeat the last cut
  -repository path                         Set the directory of MLT modules
  -serialise [filename]                    Write the commands to a text file
  -silent                                  Do not display position/transport
  -split relative-frame                    Split the last cut into two cuts
  -swap                                    Rearrange the last two cuts
  -track                                   Add a track
  -transition id[:arg] [name=value]*       Add a transition
  -verbose                                 Set the logging level to verbose
  -timings                                 Set the logging level to timings
  -version                                 Show the version and copyright
  -video-track | -hide-audio               Add a video-only track
For more help: <https://www.mltframework.org/>
```

今は、コマンドを打っても下記のような状態です。

```
melt : 用語 'melt' は、コマンドレット、関数、スクリプト ファイル、または操作可能なプログラムの名前として認識されません。名前
が正しく記述されていることを確認し、パスが含まれている場合はそのパスが正しいことを確認してから、再試行してください。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ melt
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (k:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

インストール方法をご存じの方、どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://github.com/mltframework/mlt に Configuration,  Compilation, Installation の項目がありますが、こちらは実行したのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
行いましたがそこから先が、どうすれば良いかいまいち分かりません。
https://mltframework.org/docs/install/、こちらも確認しましたが同じです。

Comment: 「いまいち」ではなく、具体的に何を実施したのかを記載した方がアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。

Comment: MLTをインストールして、PowerSellでコマンドを使えるようにしたいです。
PowerSellで『melt』とコマンドしたらオプションが出てくるように

Comment: 質問文中で参考になさったと書かれている https://www.mltframework.org/docs/windowsbuild/ には Git Bash shell を使う方法が書かれていますが、Git Bash shell をお使いになって、その上でmelt コマンドは PowerShell で実行なさいたいのでしょうか。このような感じで手順のひとつひとつが具体的に知りたいので、質問文を [edit] して必要そうな情報を追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 少なくとも今現在は公式サイトで「powershell」と検索しても何もヒットしません。インストール後に PATH さえ通せば PowerShell からも参照できるのかもしれませんが、インストールの段階では Git Bash や MinGW の環境が必要になるはずです。

Answer (score 0):

環境変数を通して、『cmake --install』コマンドを入力して、一度PowerSellを閉じて、『melt』とコマンドしたらできました。
皆さんありがとうございました。